# rjava / rserve performance issues

Tags: java, r

We are invoking machine learning R models like "SVM", "Navie Byes" from java. Java - R communication we are using RJava. Problem here is models require huge training data set. So every time model is invoked from java.. 
data is training data set (which is quite huge)
model <- naiveBayes(as.factor(RAG.Status)~., data=data)
since training data set hardly changes, is it possible  using (rjava/rserve)for model to cached and only prediction happens for test data which changes?

Answer (score 0):

Since the model is created inside R, Java has no control over caching the R environment. You could put the changed data in another file and add the tests in that file to your model data-frame through some R script, which can be run from R at specified intervals.